# Trying to query many text files in the same folder with linq

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I need to search a folder containing csv files. The records i'm interested in have 3 fields: Rec, Country and Year. My job is to search the files and see if any of the files has records for more then a single year. Below the code i have so far:

// Get each individual file from the folder.

```
 string startFolder = @"C:\MyFileFolder\";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*",
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var queryMatchingFiles =
            from file in fileList
            where (file.Extension == ".dat" || file.Extension == ".csv")
        select file;
```

Then i'm came up with this code to read year field from each file and find those where year count is more than 1(The count part was not successfully implemented)

```
public  void GetFileData(string filesname, char sep)
    {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filesname))
    {
        var recs = (from line in reader.Lines(sep.ToString())
            let parts = line.Split(sep)
             select       parts[2]);
            }
```

below a sample file:

```
 REC,IE,2014

 REC,DE,2014

 REC,FR,2015
```

Now i'am struggling to combine these 2 ideas to solve my problem in a single query. The query should list those files that have record for more than a year.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
string startFolder = @"C:\MyFileFolder\";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*",
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var fileData =
            from file in fileList
            where (file.Extension == ".dat" || file.Extension == ".csv")
        select GetFileData(file, ',')
;

public  string GetFileData(string filesname, char sep)
    {
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filesname))
       {
        var recs = (from line in reader.Lines(sep.ToString())
            let parts = line.Split(sep)
             select       parts[2]);
        var multipleyears = recs.Distinct().Count();
        if(multipleyears > 1)
        return filename;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This says nothing about more than one year in a file.

Comment: My query need to return a list of the files where i have more than just one year. Most files should only contain a single year

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. This is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

Not on my develop machine, so this might not compile "as is", but here's a direction

```
var lines = // file.readalllines();
var years = from line in lines 
           let parts = line.Split(new [] {','})
           select       parts[2]);            
var distinct_years = years.Distinct();
if (distinct_years >1 )
    // this file has several years
```

Comment: no worries. I'll clean it up once i'll have access to linqpad :)

Answer (score 1):

> "My job is to search the files and see if any of the files has records
>   for more then a single year."

This specifies that you want a Boolean result, one that says if any of the files has those records.

For fun I'll extend it a little bit more:

> My job is to get the collection of files where any of the records is about more than a single year.

You were almost there. Let's first declare a class with the records in your file:

```
public class MyRecord
{
    public string Rec { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I'll make an extension method of the class FileInfo that will read the file and returns the sequence of MyRecords that is in it.

For extension methods see [MSDN Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class FileInfoExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<MyRecord> ReadMyRecords(this FileInfo file, char separator)
    {
        var records = new List<MyRecord>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
        {
            var lineToProcess = reader.ReadLine();
            while (lineToProcess != null)
            {
                var splitLines = lineToProcess.Split(new char[] { separator }, 3);
                if (splitLines.Length < 3) throw new InvalidDataException();
                var record = new MyRecord()
                {
                    Rec = splitLines[0],
                    CountryCode = splitLines[1],
                    Year = Int32.Parse(splitLines[2]),
                };
                records.Add(record);
                lineToProcess = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        return records;
    }
}
```

I could have used string instead of FileInfo, but IMHO a string is something completely different than a filename.

After the above you can write the following:

```
string startFolder = @"C:\MyFileFolder\";
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
var allFiles = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var sequenceOfFileRecordCollections = allFiles.ReadMyRecords(',');
```

So now you have per file a sequence of the MyRecords in the file. You want to know which files have more than one year, Let's add another extension method to class FileInfoExtension:

```
public static bool IsMultiYear(this FileInfo file, char separator)
{
    // read the file, only return true if there are any records,
    // and if any record has a different year than the first record
    var myRecords = file.ReadMyRecords(separator);
    if (myRecords.Any())
    {
        int firstYear = myRecords.First().Year;
        return myRecords.Any(record => record.Year != firstYear);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The sequence of file that have more than one year in it is:

```
allFiles.Where(file => file.IsMultiYear(',');
```

Put everything in one line:

```
var allFilesWithMultiYear = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyFileFolder\")
    .EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file => file.IsMultiYear(',');
```

By creating two fairly simple extension methods your problem became one highly readable statement.